# GNU/Linux swapping blocks system

Tags: linux, swap, virtual-memory

I have used GNU/Linux on systems from 4 MB RAM to 512 GB RAM. When
they start swapping, most of the time you can still log in and kill
off the offending process - you just have to be 100-1000 times more
patient.

On my new 32 GB system that has changed: It blocks when it starts
swapping. Sometimes with full disk activity but other times with no
disk activity.

To examine what might be the issue I have written this program. The
idea is:

```
1 grab 3% of the memory free right now
2 if that caused swap to increase: stop
3 keep the chunk used for 30 seconds by forking off
4 goto 1
```

-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub freekb {
    my $free = `free|grep buffers/cache`;
    my @a=split / +/,$free;
    return $a[3];
}

sub swapkb {
    my $swap = `free|grep Swap:`;
    my @a=split / +/,$swap;
    return $a[2];
}


my $swap = swapkb();
my $lastswap = $swap;
my $free;
while($lastswap >= $swap) {
    print "$swap $free";
    $lastswap = $swap;
    $swap = swapkb();
    $free = freekb();
    my $used_mem = "x"x(1024 * $free * 0.03);
    if(not fork()) {
    sleep 30;
    exit();
    }
}
print "Swap increased $swap $lastswap\n";
```

Running the program forever ought to keep the system at the limit of
swapping, but only grabbing a minimal amount of swap and do that very
slowly (i.e. a few MB at a time at most).

If I run:

```
forever free | stdbuf -o0 timestamp > freelog
```

I ought to see swap slowly rising every second. (forever and timestamp
from https://github.com/ole-tange/tangetools).

But that is not the behaviour I see: I see swap increasing in jumps
and that the system is completely blocked during these jumps. Here the
system is blocked for 30 seconds with the swap usage increases with 1
GB:

```
secs
169.527 Swap:     18440184     154184   18286000
170.531 Swap:     18440184     154184   18286000
200.630 Swap:     18440184    1134240   17305944
210.259 Swap:     18440184    1076228   17363956
```

Blocked: 21 secs. Swap increase 2000 MB:

```
307.773 Swap:     18440184     581324   17858860
308.799 Swap:     18440184     597676   17842508
330.103 Swap:     18440184    2503020   15937164
331.106 Swap:     18440184    2502936   15937248
```

Blocked: 20 secs. Swap increase 2200 MB:

```
751.283 Swap:     18440184     885288   17554896
752.286 Swap:     18440184     911676   17528508
772.331 Swap:     18440184    3193532   15246652
773.333 Swap:     18440184    1404540   17035644
```

Blocked: 37 secs. Swap increase 2400 MB:

```
904.068 Swap:     18440184     613108   17827076
905.072 Swap:     18440184     610368   17829816
942.424 Swap:     18440184    3014668   15425516
942.610 Swap:     18440184    2073580   16366604
```

This is bad enough, but what is even worse is that the system sometimes
stops responding at all - even if I wait for hours. I have the
feeling it is related to the swapping issue, but I cannot tell for
sure.

My first idea was to tweak /proc/sys/vm/swappiness from 60 to 0 or
100, just to see if that had any effect at all. 0 did not have an
effect, but 100 did cause the problem to arise less often.

How can I prevent the system from blocking for such a long time?

Why does it decide to swapout 1-3 GB when less than 10 MB would suffice?

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux aspire 3.8.0-32-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 22:35:23 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Edit:

I tested if the problem is due to 32 GB RAM by removing 24 GB and trying with only 8 GB - I see the same behaviour.

I can also reproduce the swapping behaviour (though not the freezing) by installing GNU/Linux Mint 15 in VirtualBox.

I cannot reproduce the problem on my 8 GB laptop: The script above runs beautifully for hours and hours - swapping out a few megabytes, but never a full gigabyte. So I compared all the variables in /proc/sys/vm/* on both systems: They are exactly the same. This leads me to believe the problem is elsewhere. The laptop runs a different kernel:

```
Linux hk 3.2.0-55-generic #85-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 2 12:29:27 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Maybe something in the VM system changed from 3.2.0 to 3.8.0?

Comment: 0. The system does nothing else.

Comment: Just a honest hint: try to ask 1 question to get 1 answer. As I see you have more than one question here.

Comment: I don't mean to be a troll, but have you considered _disabling swap_?

Comment: @Otheus That would cause the system to run out of memory. But it would probably run fine until then.

Comment: Running out of memory and letting the OOM killer do its job might be preferable. Is your system primarily a server or a workstation? If it's a server, I'd say: never swap.  Anyway, I wish I could answer your question, but kernels beyond 2.4 are unknown to me.

Comment: @OleTange This problem with the way Linux works is driving me insane for a couple of months. Here I am sitting with a brand new computer that is having its performance handicapped by software problems. I've just created a new question dealing with the same bottleneck problems, maybe you can add something to the discussion? I feel I'm getting very close to diagnose the root cause of it, but I need some help. If you want an easy way to reproduce this bug, there's this game called Cities Skylines, the game relies on swap to even load, it instantly puts the system into a stress situation.

Comment: Although I would not recommend to use latest version of Cities Skylines due to updates rendering the game broken, since it will not finish loading ever, the DLC updates are just too heavy. If you want to run tests yourself, I recommend downloading older version with the Green Cities update, that was the last "usable" version of the game before becoming broken. There's an even older version which is 1.1.1c dated early 2015, shortly after launch. That one is also good to see how disk swapping will affect system performance in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappeared after upgrading to:

```
Linux aspire 3.16.0-31-lowlatency #43~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 10 20:41:36 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It is not given that it was *this* kernel upgrade, that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Check which I/O scheduler are you using on the swap block device, try changing it for better results.

http://andrux-and-me.blogspot.nl/2013/05/io-schedulers-and-performance.html

Comment: The scheduler only changes the priority of requests in the queue. There is no queue: Nothing else is using the disk.